# Is there a way to know where init scripts in Linux are stored?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init, init.d

As I asked in the title, I'm looking for a script/command to find the correct directory (usually `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d/init.d`).
Right now I'm using

```
    dirname `find / -name acpid 2> /dev/null | grep /etc/`
```

but sometimes I get more than one result (probably some of the results are link) . Any suggestion?

I'm using acpid because it is a script that should be present in almost every distribution that is not prehistoric. If someone has a suggestion for a better script, let me know, thanks :)

Comment: Which flavor of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat Enterprise, Fedora, CentOS, SuSE and other distros.

Comment: It is perfectly legitimate and normal to have the same script appear in multiple places; a single script may be used in various phases of startup and shutdown.  They can be links — symbolic or hard.  And the names in the active `rc.N` (for n in 0..6) directories can be prefixed with a number so that they are executed in sequence — at least, in the prehistoric systems I used to work with.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. What you say is perfectly normal, because in each runlevel (identified by a directory of the type rcN.d) there's a script to start or kill every init script. Anyway I'm searching just the script, not the links that refer to it. So the question is, again: is it normal that the same script (not the links) is in more directories? Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your approach is quite good as the location of the startup scripts is distro-dependable. Simply add *-type f* option to exclude links from your results.

```
INITDIR=`find / -type f -name acpid 2> /dev/null | grep /etc/`
```